# Create a table based on the row and column numbers and fill it

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object which has an `array` and two properties; `rows` and `columns`. I want to draw a table based on these two properties and fill my `myObject`'s array elements into it. But this will be dynamically, because the properties changes from object to another object.

For example the possible combinations might be:

```
myObject.array   = ["x1","x2","x3","x4"];

myObject.rows    = 2;
myObject.columns = 2; 
// then draw this table
-----------
| x1 | x2 |
-----------
| x3 | x4 |
-----------
    OR
myObject.rows    = 1;
myObject.columns = 4;
// then draw this table
---------------------
| x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 |
---------------------
    OR
myObject.rows    = 4;
myObject.columns = 1;
// then draw this table
------
| x1 |
------
| x2 |
------
| x3 |
------
| x4 |
------
    OR
myObject.array   = [12 elements]    
myObject.rows    = 3;
myObject.columns = 4;
.....................
```

I've also a pipe to loop by numbers with ngFor:

```
@Pipe({name: 'fill'})
export class FillPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value) {
    let number = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < value; i++) {
      number.push(i);
    }

    return number;
  }
}
```

Can you guide me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question answered here: [How to use Angular2 templates with *ngFor to create a table out of nested arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699962/how-to-use-angular2-templates-with-ngfor-to-create-a-table-out-of-nested-arrays)